# Check null condition for string date conversion to DateTime inside object

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I am assigning values to class object in loop and apparently I am getting error due to date null value.

My question is can I use LINQ to check value inside object

```
foreach (var item in _query)
{
    EnrolmentList.Add(new EnrolmentEntity
    {
        PeopleUnitsID = item.PeopleUnitsID,
        PersonCode = item.PersonCode,
        UnitType = item.UnitType,
        ProgressCode = item.ProgressCode,
        ProgressStatus = item.ProgressStatus,
        ProgressDate = Convert.ToDateTime(item.ProgressDate),
        UnitInstanceID = item.UnitInstanceID,
        UnitInstanceOccurrenceID = item.UnitInstanceOccurrenceID,
        CourseCode = item.CourseCode,
        OwningOrganisation = item.OwningOrganisation,
        CalendarOccurrenceCode = item.CalendarOccurrenceCode,
        FES_Start_Date = Convert.ToDateTime(item.FES_Start_Date),
        AimStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(item.AimStartDate)
    });
}
```

there are three date variable that I need to check if they are null or not. If null then I need to ignore that rather then to convert them to date

Comment: Where are you creating `_query`? They can only be null if it is a string or a `Nullable<DateTime>`. Also please show an example of how the `ProgressDate`, `FES_Start_Date` and `AimStartDate` look like. Are they strings?

Comment: How are your dates "null"?  That doesn't exist unless they are nullable dates.  Regular dates are value types.  Edit:  I see you are trying to *convert* them to dates.  Well, what are they before that?

Comment: You should simplify example that shows the exact problem (an exception for instance), including data types you use, otherwise the question is vague.

Comment: many thanks for guiding me, I have also update my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have check string null for date conversation as;

```
  public class EnrolmentEntity
{

    public DateTime? ProgressDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime? FES_Start_Date { get; set; }

    public DateTime? AimStartDate { get; set; }
}
```

//

```
 public class Enrolments
 {    
    [XmlElement("PROGRESS_STATUS")]
    public string ProgressStatus { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("PROGRESS_DATE")]
    public string ProgressDate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("FES_START_DATE")]
    public string FES_Start_Date  { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("AIM_START")]
    public string AimStartDate { get; set; } 

 }
```

//

```
foreach (var item in _query)
   {
     EnrolmentList.Add(new EnrolmentEntity
      {
        PeopleUnitsID = item.PeopleUnitsID,
        PersonCode = item.PersonCode,
        UnitType = item.UnitType,
        ProgressCode = item.ProgressCode,
        ProgressStatus = item.ProgressStatus,
        ProgressDate = string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ProgressDate) ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(item.ProgressDate), 
        UnitInstanceID = item.UnitInstanceID,
        UnitInstanceOccurrenceID = item.UnitInstanceOccurrenceID,
        CourseCode = item.CourseCode,
        OwningOrganisation = item.OwningOrganisation,
        CalendarOccurrenceCode = item.CalendarOccurrenceCode,
        FES_Start_Date = string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.FES_Start_Date) ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(item.FES_Start_Date), 
        AimStartDate = string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.AimStartDate)? (DateTime?)null :DateTime.Parse(item.AimStartDate)  
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove the items from the query you can add

```
.Where(item => item.ProgressDate != null)
```

to the query.

If you want to not parse the Dates that are null but still use the items you can use

```
ProgressDate = item.ProgressDate != null ? Convert.ToDateTime(item.ProgressDate) :null
```

inside your object creation

Answer (score 1):

From the use of the `Convert.ToDateTime()` function I assume your data is of `string` type. 
Use the `?:` operator check if it is null. If it is then use a default `DateTime` value, otherwise convert.

```
var defaultDate = DateTime.MinValue;
EnrolmentList.AddRange(_query.Select(item => new EnrolmentEntity
    {
        PeopleUnitsID = item.PeopleUnitsID,
        PersonCode = item.PersonCode,
        UnitType = item.UnitType,
        ProgressCode = item.ProgressCode,
        ProgressStatus = item.ProgressStatus,
        ProgressDate = item.ProgressDate == null ? defaultDate : Convert.ToDateTime(item.ProgressDate),
        UnitInstanceID = item.UnitInstanceID,
        UnitInstanceOccurrenceID = item.UnitInstanceOccurrenceID,
        CourseCode = item.CourseCode,
        OwningOrganisation = item.OwningOrganisation,
        CalendarOccurrenceCode = item.CalendarOccurrenceCode,
        FES_Start_Date = item.FES_Start_Date == null ? defaultDate : Convert.ToDateTime(item.FES_Start_Date),
        AimStartDate = item.AimStartDate == null ? defaultDate : Convert.ToDateTime(item.AimStartDate)
    }));
```

*Also, you can replace the `foreach` + `Add` with a `.Select` + `AddRange`*

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your 3 input dates are typeof DateTime? AND you want default(DateTime) in case of null you can use `GetValueOrDefault()`

```
foreach (var item in _query)
        {
            EnrolmentList.Add(new EnrolmentEntity
            {
                PeopleUnitsID = item.PeopleUnitsID,
                PersonCode = item.PersonCode,
                UnitType = item.UnitType,
                ProgressCode = item.ProgressCode,
                ProgressStatus = item.ProgressStatus,
                ProgressDate = item.ProgressDate.GetValueOrDefault(),
                UnitInstanceID = item.UnitInstanceID,
                UnitInstanceOccurrenceID = item.UnitInstanceOccurrenceID,
                CourseCode = item.CourseCode,
                OwningOrganisation = item.OwningOrganisation,
                CalendarOccurrenceCode = item.CalendarOccurrenceCode,
                FES_Start_Date = item.FES_Start_Date.GetValueOrDefault(),
                AimStartDate = item.AimStartDate.GetValueOrDefault()
            });
        }
```